# Writing to a specific line of a file

Tags: file, vb6

I have a .dat file with data like this in

```
"James","Project5","15/05/2010","3"
"Matt","Project1","01/05/2010","5"
"Ellie","Project5","24/04/2010","1"
"Ellie","Project2","10/05/2010","3"
"Matt","Project3","03/05/2010","4"
```

It gets written in with thise code.

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()
Open jobs For Append As #1
Write #1, Combo1, Combo3, Combo2, Text3
Close #1
End Sub
```

I instead would like to write it to the file so that if a persons name is already in the file then it would just put the data in the file, under their that is already there but without the name. I can't figure out how to do this but this is what I would like it to end up like.

```
"James","Project5","15/05/2010","3"
"Matt","Project1","01/05/2010","5"
"Ellie","Project5","24/04/2010","1"
"Project2","10/05/2010","3"
"Matt","Project3","03/05/2010","4"
```

Any help would be fantastic!

Comment: How would you ever read such a file back?  I don't see anything there to tell your program "the next record is in short-format and extends the previous record."

Comment: If the record is in what you call "short-format", then it speaks for itself -- any record with only three entries extends the previous record.

Answer (score 2):

1. First read in the whole file into memory and store it as an array (read it in as one long string and the `Split` it on `vbNewLine`).
2. Then loop through the array and do your changes.
3. Write the data to a temporary filename.
4. Replace the original file with the temporary file. FSO (File System Objects) have some easy to use functions to delete and move files.

Comment: @ho don't forget to split on commas. It might be better to create an object.

Comment: Well, I see the split on commas as part of step 2. But I agree that I'd probably end up creating an object to do the work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ini file for your schema. For example:

```
[James]  
project1=01/05/2010,5  
project2=24/04/2010,1
```